# How to measure a non-normal stochastic process?

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-processes, itos-lemma

If I understand right, Itô's lemma tells us that for any process $X$ that can be adapted to an underlying standard normal Wiener measure $\mathrm dB_t$, and any twice continuously differentiable function $f$,
$$\mathrm df(X_t) = f'(X_t)\mathrm dX_t + \frac 1 2 f''(X_t)\mathrm d[X_t] ,$$
where $$[X_t]=\lim_{\|\Pi\|\rightarrow0}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(X_{t_i}-X_{t_{i-1}}\right)^2,$$
$0=t_0 < \cdots < t_n=t$, and $\|\Pi\|=\max_{1\le k\le n}|t_k-t_{k-1}|$, is the quadratic variation.  We are allowed to ignore all higher power variations because all cumulants higher than the second vanish for the normal distribution.  But [the additivity of cumulants under convolution](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/3667/skewness-and-kurtosis-under-aggregation) leads us naturally to consider a stochastic process based on an arbitrary distribution subject only to the requirements that it be infinitely divisible and possess a moment-generating function.  So if we let $A_t$ be the constant-linear-drift+martingale process having such a distribution, and we define the higher power variations
$$[A_t]_n=\lim_{\|\Pi\|\rightarrow0}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(A_{t_i}-A_{t_{i-1}}\right)^n,$$
then these all exist and are equal to the corresponding *cumulants* of the distribution of $A_t$.  This complicates Itô's lemma, which, again if I understand right, must now be written:
$$\mathrm df(X_t) = f'(X_t)\mathrm dX_t + \sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac 1{n!} f^{(n)}(X_t)\mathrm d[X_t]_n ,$$ but this is not so bad, because all these higher power variations converge in probability and scale linearly with time, except that now we need $f$ to be infinitely differentiable.  So, starting off from here, what are the most important consequences to stochastic calculus of refusing to assume that a process can be adapted to a measure based on a normal distribution?

Comment: Hi. Did you find an answer to your question? Can you share your findings by providing either an example for, say, some non-normal alpha-stable distribution or pointing to relevant references? Many thanks

Answer (score 4):

The standard method to manage your kind of problem (i.e. dealing with stochastic processes that are note presented or built thanks to a Brownian motion) is to use a measure change.

The power of Brownian motion is that you have a lot of representation theorems (Doob-Meyer theorem, Wold theorem, etc) that allows to (thanks to a change of measure or a localization method), provides you a way to define a space in which your process (or the residual of your process once you *removed* easy to deal with components) behaves like a martingale. So you can use Itô on it.

The only effects that can *change* the Itô formula should be:

- jumps (but you have an Itô semi-martingale formula as far as the Jumps are of Lévy-type, see for instance [Jacod-Shiryaev](http://books.google.fr/books?hl=fr&id=sUgXKpUIdHwC) or [Cont-Tankov](http://books.google.fr/books?id=bVlieV8GBrIC))
- fractional Brownian motion (but here again you have an Itô-like formula, see form instance [Stochastic Calculus for Fractional Brownian Motion, I. Theory, by Duncan](http://kuscholarworks.ku.edu/dspace/bitstream/1808/278/1/dhp.pdf))

For others you should first think about the proper *cleaning* of the process and change of measure before doing something fancy I think.

Comment: A change in measure can be thought of as a shift or translation of the **cumulant-generating function** so that it passes through the origin with the desired slope -- this slope will be the mean of the new measure.  The new measure $\mathbb Q$ is then related to the old measure $\mathbb P$ by $$\frac{\mathrm d\mathbb Q}{\mathrm d\mathbb P}=\frac {e^{cA_t}}{M_{\mathbb P}(c)}$$ where $M_{\mathbb P}(c)$ is the **moment-generating function** of $A_t$ under the old measure evaluated at the point $c$ that was found.