# How to annualize kurtosis of returns (in simple terms)?

Tags: time-series, finance, statistics, estimation, annualized

I'm confused by [this post](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/3956/how-to-annualize-skewness-and-kurtosis-based-on-daily-returns) on how to annualize kurtosis. I don't understand how to apply it to annualize the kurtosis for my data. In other words, if I evaluated the kurtosis of, say, **monthly** returns (computed by $r_{t+1}=\frac{Price(t+1)}{Price(t)}-1$), what is the number I should multiply it by to get the **annualized** kurtosis?

Comment: Does this help? https://quant.stackexchange.com/q/3667/848

Comment: Hello Bob! Yes, I also read your post,  but again I didn't find an affirmative answer for the linear returns. The answer there is given for log returns. And this confuses me.

Comment: Hi; assuming that 1) the returns are independent across time 2) returns are sufficiently small, you could approximate the moments and moment scaling behaviour of $z_{t,N}\equiv\prod_{i=1}^N(1+r_{t-i+1})-1$ with the same properties as under log returns. In any case, you could verify your assumptions / results using simulation studies.