Is there such a thing as monthly/yearly skewness and kurtosis?
As the title suggests, when performing regression analysis or portfolio optimization, one must adjust the frequency of his variables to match the frequency of other variables in the problem. For example, a regression of a monthly return against the Black-Scholes IV, the annualized Black-Scholes IV must be divided by $\sqrt{12}$ to arrive at a monthly Black-Scholes IV.
Therefore, is there such a thing as a monthly/yearly skewness or kurtosis? How does one convert the daily skewness/kurtosis calculated from a set of daily returns to that of a monthly frequency?

Maybe these help: https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/j.1540-6288.1989.tb00340.x https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1635484

As well as this and similar threads: https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/3956/how-to-annualize-skewness-and-kurtosis-based-on-daily-returns

Assuming $n$ independent and identically distributed returns $X_i$, all moments of the distribution of the cumulative return $Y=\sum_{i=1}^n x_i$ scale with $n$:
$$
\mathrm{E}(Y^k)\propto n\mathrm{E}(X^k)
$$
For the skewness, this implies
$$
S(Y)\equiv \frac{\mathrm{E}\left(\left(Y-\mathrm{E}(Y)\right)^3\right)}{\left.\mathrm{E}\left(\left(Y-\mathrm{E}(Y)\right)^2\right)\right.^{1.5}}\propto\frac{n}{n^{1.5}}S(X)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}S(X)
$$
For kurtosis, $K(Y)\propto \frac{1}{n}K(X)$.
Hence the notion that - assuming independent return contributions - monthly/quarterly/annual returns will look more and more normal.

Thank you @Kermittfrog, I very much appreciate this clear and concise answer. It is interesting to see this proven mathematically!

And for my record:
$$ S(Y) = \frac{E([Y-E(Y)]^3)}{E([Y-E(Y)]^2)^{1.5}} \propto \frac{nE([X-E(X)]^3)}{[nE([X-E(X)]^2)]^{1.5}} = \frac{n}{n^{1.5}}S(X) $$
