# Does heteroskedasticity of returns depend on the time frame?

Tags: time-series, returns, reference-request, variance

Similarly to [my last question](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/18367/can-gaussianity-of-returns-depend-on-the-time-frame), for which I obtained very interesting and useful answers, I would like to know if there has been any study regarding heteroskedasticity and time-frames of the returns.

As an example could it be that the lower the time frame (take the 5 minute returns) the less heteroskedastic are returns?

Comment: Hi Monolite! Can you specify what is the model you're referring to (GARCH, ARCH, ...)?

Answer (score 2):

In practice, for heavily traded assets (above 60% quantile of average daily dollar volume), individual asset return is pretty scalable across different time frame by a factor of $\sqrt{T}$.

However, for covariance among different assets, moving between different time frame is not linearly scalable (although it should be in math). This is known as "Epps Effect".

Answer (score 1):

This paper states that heteroskedasticity is a stylized fact in daily as well as intra-day returns:  https://statistik.econ.kit.edu/download/doc_secure1/HandbookITandFinan.pdf