# Where can I find a list of VaR and CVaR formulas for continuous distributions?

Tags: risk, value-at-risk

Where can I find more VaR and CVaR formulas for continuous distributions?

I collected a list here:
[image]

Answer (score 9):

Values of `VaR` are just the inverses of the cumulative distributions.

`CVaR` is not a very commonly used term, its more frequently used synonym is `Expected Shortfall`. See http://www.maths.manchester.ac.uk/~saralees/chap17.pdf for the list of Expected Shortfall values for more than 20 distributions.

Comment: I am looking for a list of $VaR$ and $CVaR$ together, because the notation for the distribution function differs sometimes?

Comment: @emcor: in the doc I have referenced, the author gives you the CDFs before deriving ESs. VaR = inverse of CDF!

Comment: I doubt that you can find any of the 20 inverses there yourself, except for maybe normal distribution. So its useless to give the cdf without inverse.

Comment: Well, in most cases cdfs are not in known in closed form, so you would have to inverse them numerically. For normal distribution, you usually have numerical methods to compute thw inverse of CDF. For most others, you will be inverting them numerically.

Comment: The question is on **formulas** for VaR and CVaR.

Comment: I disagree with your assertion that CVaR is not a commonly used term. They are interchangeable, as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: Great link I think. +1

Answer (score 3):

More often than not, I prefer to work with a scenario representation. That is, I will simulate from the distribution and calculate the VaR and CVaR as appropriate. This is especially the case for forward-looking analysis of portfolios' CVaR, rather than in evaluating the historical returns of some portfolio.

If for some reason I can't do the scenario approach, then I will use the Cornish-Fisher approximation. There is a [paper](http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1024151) by Boudt, Peterson, and Croux that I think provides the formula for both VaR and CVaR, as well as a few others (perhaps refer to other references, and there's already a [question](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/3646/how-does-cornish-fisher-var-aka-modified-var-scale-with-time) on this site about it wrt VaR). If you're using Cornish-Fisher, then you can write the VaR and CVaR in terms of the moments of whatever distribution you're looking at. BPC provides the formula for portfolios as well, but in my experience this is a big pain.

Comment: Thanks for your insight. However, I was looking for some exact formulas of VaR, CVaR for different parametric distributions just for research purposes...

Comment: Other than the one posted by @YuliaV, I'm not aware of any papers like that off the top of my head. In practice, I just don't use the analytic formula often (really only for normal VaR). Not sure how common that is for others.

Comment: @John, could you please give a reference on scenario approach?

Comment: @Nick The original work by Rockafellar and Urysev describes the scenario approach. See equation 17 of http://www.ise.ufl.edu/uryasev/files/2011/11/CVaR1_JOR.pdf

Answer (score 1):

The paper "[Calculating CVaR and bPOE for Common Probability Distributions With Application to Portfolio Optimization and Density Estimation](https://arxiv.org/abs/1811.11301)" by Norton, Matthew; Khokhlov, Valentyn; Uryasev, Stan (2018) gives a large number of CVAR analytical formula with full proof.

Most of them can also be found on the [Expected shortfall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_shortfall) (aka CVAR) Wikipedia page.